# Ionic lists, using animation on remove item and ui-sref causes that both are triggered on a delete

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have three cases:

1.- If I use **item-remove-animate** (it animates the delete action)  and **ui-sref** (it makes the item clickable to send the user to another view), when I delete an item, it gets **deleted** but also, the ui-sref **redirect** is triggered.

2.- If I remove the animation class 'item-remove-animate", it works as I expect, the item is deleted and I'm still on the same view. The problem is that the items are deleted instantly, I would like to conserve the animation.

3.- If I remove the ui-sref, the animation works as expected but I lose the redirect.

Here it is the complete view I'm using, in the first case:

**HTML:**

```
<ion-view title="Bimbo Keepers">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left"><a ng-click="onShowDeleteIcons()" ng-if="reportes.length" class="button button-icon icon ion-minus-circled"></a></ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-content padding="true" class="has-bottom-icons">
    <div class="row">
      <h1>Enviados</h1>
    </div>
    <ion-list show-delete="data.showDelete">
      <ion-item ng-repeat="reporte in reportes.slice().reverse()" type="item-text-wrap" ui-sref="tab.detail-enviados({id: reporte.id})" class="item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right item-remove-animate item item-complex item-left-editable item-right-editable">
        <ion-delete-button ng-click="onReporteDelete(reporte)" class="ion-minus-circled"></ion-delete-button>
        <img ng-src="{{ reporte.imagen1_base64 }}"/>
        <h2>Reporte No: {{reporte.id}}</h2>
        <p>Envíado el {{reporte.fecha}}</p><i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <div ng-if="!reportes.length" class="container">
      <p>No has enviado reportes. Desde la pantalla de Reportes Guardados, utiliza el botón sincronizar.</p>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Here it is a CodePen:
http://codepen.io/jdsampayo/pen/QbLggv

Any help will be appreciated to conserve the animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `$event` object in `onReporteDelete` function and stop event bubbling by using `stopPropagation`.

[Updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdWXMa)

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try using event.preventdefault() - that might fix your problem. However, if you can provide a jsbin link, it will be better to debug the problem.
Use the event.preventDefault() in the ondelete function that you have.

Comment: I have added a CodePen, don't know where I can prevent the event.